# Finite Element Software: cyclic-symmetric problems including gyroscopic terms

Tags: cad, scientific-computing

Do you know of a Finite Element Software (commercial like *Ansys* or preferably open source like *CalculiX*) that is able to **compute gyroscopic terms** for cyclic-symmetric structures ? Most FE-softwares with rotordynamic capabilites allow this operation for the full structure but are unable to do so when meshing a single sector.

The idea is to carry out a complex modal analysis for a given spatial harmonic (or nodal diameter) accounting for gyroscopic effects based on a single sector model.

I'm using Linux. But have also access to Windows

Comment: What Operating System do you use or would you be willing to switch for this program?

Comment: I'm using Linux. But have also access to Windows